# ngrx entity why order matters

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity

Currently I'm studying ngrx entity and I read in [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/ngrx-entity/) blog post, that with this feature, we basically say, that our entities are like database tables. But I don't unterstand one thing. Why is there a focus on the order in the collections? Because if I have a database, I don't care about the order in the table, I just select the data in the order I want it. And that could be maybe  done the ngrx way via selectors too.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.
The order is of no importance for entities.
If you want to sort results, this can better be done in the selector (or component).